# MassTransit implementation for node.js

Tags: esb, masstransit

We have the multi-platform system which I need to communicate between node.Js and `.net` Core microservices with ESB. The system runs on premises.

We already started to use MassTransit in our `.net` services.
Is there a way to publish/consume messages with `node.js` using the MassTransit platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MassTransit Interoperability with non-.NET services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558358/masstransit-interoperability-with-non-net-services)